# « Dans ce sens » ou « en ce sens »: « J’ai apporté une correction au texte dans ce sens/en ce sens. »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> J’ai lu votre commentaire et j’ai apporté une correction au texte dans ce sens.

> J’ai lu votre commentaire et j’ai apporté une correction au texte en ce sens.

J’ai rectifié le texte dans ce sens (en tenant compte de votre observation).

J’ai rectifié le texte en ce sens (en tenant compte de votre observation).

Comment: Et donc…Quelle serait alors la bonne formulation?

Comment: C’est bien des explications mais ce le serait encore mieux si elles étaient accompagnées d’une réponse explicite à la question demandée.

Comment: Bon, si le ciel des gallois ne me tombent pas sur la tête, la réponse que vous m'avez demandé se trouve au bon endroit.

Comment: Corrections: Bon, si le ciel des gallois ne me **tombe** sur la tête, la réponse que vous m’avez **demandée** se trouve au bon endroit.

Comment: Maybe I don't want to broadcast myself as female. Ouais, certainement, j'avais peur que les gallois me tomb*ent* sur la tête.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les deux expressions (*en/dans ce sens*) se disent, sinon, voici une autre possibilité :

> J'ai tenu compte de votre commentaire pour rectifier mon texte.

Answer (score 0):

"J’ai lu votre commentaire et j’ai apporté une correction au texte dans ce sens".

*dans ce sens*, c'est pour indiquer une direction. Alors, à mon avis, cela ne marche pas dans la phrase ci-dessus.

Voici un exemple de "dans ce sens" qui veut dire: dans cette direction:
"Continuer **dans ce sens** jusqu'au carrefour, puis, tournez à droite".

Alors,
"J’ai lu votre commentaire et j’ai apporté une correction au texte **en ce sens".**

marche bien, puisque la signification d'une phrase peut se corriger.

Comment: J’en conviens, mais la phrase n’aurait-elle pas pu aussi signifier « j’ai rectifié mon propos/la phrase dans la direction de votre commentaire », non?

Comment: @Pogo Il faut attendre la collaboration des villageois gallois.

Comment: @Lambie Que diable viennent faire les Gallois dans cette galère ?

Comment: Le prince Charles, de Gaule vient de débarquer !

Comment: @jlliagre Ce sont ceux qui cultivent les Idéfixes.

Comment: @Lambie *Paid a drysu Gâl a Chymraeg!*

Comment: Je suis sûre qu'Astérix pardonerait la reine des fôtes d'orthographe.

Answer (score 0):

Vous m'avez dit de mettre **plus** d'émotion dans les dialogues, j'ai corrigé le texte **dans** ce sens.
(Plus indique une direction).

Vous m'avez dit que vous aimiez la légèreté, j'ai corrigé le texte en ce sens.

Comment: À mon avis « plus » indique une intensité, non une direction.